# Connect automatically to a Google Plus Account

Tags: php, google-plus, google-authentication

I'd like to link my google plus account to my web site, using php, in order to display posts from my google plus account (without going through the autentification process). Is that doable, and if it is what google api should I use ?

Regards

Comment: Please read [ask] to improve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only retrieve public posts for any account. The broad answer is that you can perform API calls to the [activities.list](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/list) API method as an unauthenticated app and can retrieve public posts for users with specific user IDs (1xxxxxxxxxxx rather than "me").

You can use the [Google Client library for PHP](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/) to make the requests easier. Assuming you have a fully connected `Google_client` object and an instantiated `Google_PlusService`, you would be able to call:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('My Google+ PHP App');
// Visit https://code.google.com/apis/console?api=plus to generate your
// client id, client secret, and to register your redirect uri.
$client->setClientId('insert_your_oauth2_client_id');
$client->setClientSecret('insert_your_oauth2_client_secret');
$client->setRedirectUri('insert_your_oauth2_redirect_uri');
$client->setDeveloperKey('insert_your_simple_api_key');
$plus = new Google_PlusService($client);
$posts = $plus->activities->listActivities('106189723444098348646', 'public', array());
```

The example above would retrieve the first page of Larry Page's public posts.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! I tried your code by replacing with my parameters but I have an error  
Fatal error: Cannot unset string offsets in C:\wamp\www\google-api-php-client-0.6.7\google-api-php-client\src\service\Google_ServiceResource.php on line 95

Comment: It works finally. I replace $plus->activities->list by $plus->activities->listActivities and it works well ! Thanks again !